# How to serve css files in djangos's flatpages?

Tags: css, django, django-templates, hyperlink, django-flatpages

I'm building a basic site and thought of using the flatpages app for a couple of pages. Problem is, I'm not sure how to serve static files in my flatpages.
The link in my flatpage template is this:

```
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/base.css" />
```

However, firebug shows that file is being looked at:

```
  localhost:8000/example_flatpage/static/base.css
```

instead of

```
  localhost:8000/static/base.css
```

Infact, every link in the template works this way.
Instead of
      localhost:8000/home/

```
  localhost:8000/example_flatpage/home/
```

Here's my default flatpage template:

```
  <html><head>
  <title>title</title>
  <link type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" href="static/favicon.ico" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/base.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  mainly plain text
  </body>
  </html>
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Check your STATIC_URL setting in settings.py

Comment: szaman, that would be '/static/'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `"/static/base.css"` instead of `"static/base.css"`. The first one is a path relative to root `'/'`, while the second form is a path relative to the current page.